# unexpected token import in ES2017 with babel and Jest

Tags: node.js, babeljs, jestjs, ecmascript-2017

I try to use [Jest](https://facebook.github.io/jest) with bablejs and ES2017 in my project, according to the Jest Getting Started page and also [Bablejs config for ES2017](https://babeljs.io/docs/plugins/preset-es2017/) this is my `.babelrc` file :

```
{
  "presets": ["es2017"],
  "env": {
    "test": {
      "presets": ["es2017"]
    }
  }
}
```

And my `package.json` is:

```
{
  "name": "",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "jest"
  },
  "repository": {
    "type": "git",
    "url": ""
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "bugs": {
    "url": ""
  },
  "homepage": "",
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-cli": "^6.26.0",
    "babel-core": "^6.26.0",
    "babel-jest": "^21.2.0",
    "babel-polyfill": "^6.26.0",
    "babel-preset-es2017": "^6.24.1",
    "jest": "^21.2.1"
  }
}
```

When I type `npm test` to run all my test with jest i get these error :

```
 ){import StateList from './StateList';
                                                                                         
   ^^^^^^
  SyntaxError: Unexpected token import
```

It means it doesn't know `import`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`babel-preset-es2017` does not transform `import` statements, because it only includes the plugins: `syntax-trailing-function-commas` and
`transform-async-to-generator`.

When installing `babel-preset-es2017` you also get a warning that it has been deprecated in favour of [`babel-preset-env`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/babel-preset-env), which contains everything that the `es201x` presets contained and more.

```
warning babel-preset-es2017@6.24.1:   Thanks for using Babel: we recommend using babel-preset-env now: please read babeljs.io/env to update!
```

As shown in the [Migration guide from es2015 to env](https://babeljs.io/env), it is a drop-in replacement.

```
npm install --save-dev babel-preset-env
```

And change your `.babelrc` to:

```
{
  "presets": ["env"]
}
```

Do not confuse `babel-preset-env` with [Babel's `env` option](https://babeljs.io/docs/usage/babelrc#env-option), which I have removed from your current config, since you are using the exact same presets for the `test` environment as for any other, so it doesn't have any effect.

You can configure `babel-preset-env` to only transform features that are not supported by the platform you target, for example `{ "targets": { "node": "current" } }` will only transform features that aren't supported by the Node version you are running. If no targets are specified, it will transform everything. For details see the [Env preset documentation](https://babeljs.io/docs/plugins/preset-env).

*Note: With the upcoming version 7 of Babel, the official packages will be published under the namespace `@babel`, which means that `babel-preset-env` will be [`@babel/preset-env`](https://github.com/babel/babel/tree/master/packages/babel-preset-env).*

Comment: when i add `{ "targets": { "node": "current" } }` then i get error: `invalid option base.targets`